# GET / POST using Clarion

Tags: clarion

I have Clarion 9 app that I want to be able to communicate with HTTP servers. I come from PHP background. I have 0 idea on what to do.

What I wish to be able to do:

- Parse JSON data and convert QUEUE data to JSON [Done]
- Have a global variable like 'baseURL' that points to e.g. `http://localhost.com` [Done]
- Call functions such `apiConnection.get('/users')` would return me the contents of the page. [I'm stuck here]
- `apiConnection.post('/users', myQueueData)` would POST myQueueData contents.

I tried using winhttp.dll by reading it from LibMaker but it didn't read it. Instead, I'm now using **wininet.dll** which LibMaker successfully created a .lib file for it.

I'm currently using the PROTOTYPE procedures from this code on GitHub https://gist.github.com/ddur/34033ed1392cdce1253c

What I did was include them like:

**SimpleApi.clw**

```
PROGRAM
     INCLUDE('winInet.equ')
      ApiLog    QUEUE, PRE(log)
      LogTitle  STRING(10)
      LogMessage    STRING(50)
     END

     MAP
      INCLUDE('winInetMap.clw')
     END

     INCLUDE('equates.clw'),ONCE 
     INCLUDE('DreamyConnection.inc'),ONCE

     ApiConnection     DreamyConnection

CODE

    IF DreamyConnection.initiateConnection('http://localhost')
       ELSE
          log:LogTitle = 'Info'
          log:LogMessage = 'Failed'
          ADD(apiLog)
    END
```

But the buffer that winInet's that uses always returns 0.

I have created a GitHub repository https://github.com/spacemudd/clarion-api with all the code to look at.

I'm really lost in this because I can't find proper documentation of Clarion.

I **do not want a paid solution**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It kind of depends which version of Clarion you have.
Starting around v9 they added ClaRunExt which provides this kind of functionality via .NET Interop.

From the help:

> Use HTTP or HTTPS to download web pages, or any other type of file. You can also post form data to web servers. Very easy way to send HTTP web requests (and receive responses) to Web Servers, REST Web Services, or standard Web Services, with the most commonly used HTTP verbs; POST, GET, PUT, and DELETE.

Otherwise, search the `LibSrc\` directory for "http" and you will get an idea of what is already there. `abapi.inc` for example, appears to provide a wrapper around wininet.lib.